# How to write the SQL in the following scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two table, also two column are the same between them

```
table1:
id, date

table2:
id, date
```

The problem is , how to update the id of table 2 that can match the date in 2 table , that means, e.g.

```
update table2 set table2.id = table1.id Where table1.date = table2.date
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update t2 set t2.id = t1.id 
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t1.date = t2.date
```

**`Edit`**

```
update t2 set t2.id = t1.id 
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t1.date = t2.date
where convert(date,t2.date)>'2013/01/01' --YYYY/MM/DD if your Date column is datetime.
```

Comment: sorry but set t2.id = t2.id ?

Comment: @user782104 by mistake **`:)`**

Comment: how about adding a condition where t2.date > xxx?

Comment: @user782104 please look at the updated answer.